# Autocomplete like lookup with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I store user account data such as name, dob, email, etc. on a DDB table.

The PK is a UUID
The SK is DocumentType: which translates into different possible document type for each user like AccountInfo, Preferences, etc.

One of the attributes under AccountInfo is username

What I'm building requires an autocomplete functionality, "begins with" like functionality. i.e a user may want to look up another user by starting to typer their username. This is not fuzzy matching, just simple start with. Results would be returned after the first letter typed.

Assume number of users are in the millions.

How can I achieve this with best possible performance whilst still being efficient?

Already thought of ideas that [I think] won't work

Having the username as PK or SK won't make difference. It won't make sense to put, say, 1m+ usernames under one PK so I can use the SK begins with functionally.

GSI won't help, similar to above.

Another table with PK being first letter.. ending up in [only] 26 PKs: don't think it's enough partitions to distribute workload. Assume, hypothetically, that there are millions of usernames under each letter. Results need to be returned after each typed/deleted letter (say 1 second delay). Usernames can be up to 20 in length.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use ZeroETL with OpenSearch and make use of that service for what it's intended where you can create an index on username and OpenSearch can do pattern matching.

In DynamoDB you can use username as the sort key. You say it doesn't make sense to have millions of items like that, but why not? Every key stroke you can do a Query with SK begins_with.

Comment: Does it make sense to include all users under 1 parition or say even 26 paritions? 

Imagine there are millions of users as I said in my original post.. that doesn't sound like a good design.

Comment: Why is it a bad design? If you store them all in a single item, and you want to update one users info, it will cost 200 WCU. If they all have their own item, it will cost 1-2 WCU. 100 - 200 X more cost efficient.

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to hot partition? Limit DDB's horizontal scalability?

Isn't DDB designed to work best when data is distributed evenly across its partitions?

Comment: Why would it be hot? You and 400KB of data in a single item, now you spread it out over 400 * 1KB items. Nothing has changed.

Comment: I am missing something here or unable to get my head around what you are saying. Patience please. Are you saying have PK=SomeStaticValue, SK=Username?  So will end up with something like [PK=SameStaticValue, SK=user1], [PK=SameStaticValue, SK=User2], [PK=SameStaticValue, SK=User3], [PK=SameStaticValue, SK=User20million], etc. ? Then simply do getitem PK=SameStaticValue and PK begins_with to do lookup/autocomplete?

Comment: To be able to use beings_with on the SK, the PK should be provided. In my design it's UUID. It's unique for each item. While user is typing, I would have no prior knowledge of it. In fact, this exercise is to retrieve it.

Comment: In that case free text lookup functionality on OpenSearch is the best solution. Only replicate usernames and UUID to keep your OS Domain small and cost effective.